# How to get computer and user info accessing a java web application hosted on apache tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

I need the user details as to keep records of the frequency of the users accessing my web application which is being hosted on tomcat server. Is there any clear cut way to access PCName or Web browser credentials to help in maintaining the records?

Comment: You may want to investigate "cookies" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by writing some code. The following code is good to go:

```
package userinfo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class UserInfoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("Headers<hr/>");

        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();

        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            out.print("Header Name: <em>" + headerName);
            String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
            out.print("</em>, Header Value: <em>" + headerValue);
            out.println("</em><br/>");
        }

    }
}
```